# Cannot append a Rust vector to another vector

Tags: rust

I am doing a Leetcode question in Rust and ran into the following error:

```
fn plus_one(digits: &mut Vec<u32>) -> &Vec<u32> {
    for i in (0.. digits.len()).rev() {
        if digits[i] < 10 {
            digits[i] = digits[i] + 1;
            break;
        }else{
            digits[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    if(digits[0] == 0) {
        let mut new_digits : Vec<u32> = vec![1];
        new_digits.extend(digits).        // This is the error
    }

    digits
}
```

The got error:

```
--> src/easy/plus_one.rs:13:20
   |
13 |         new_digits.extend(digits)
   |                    ^^^^^^ the trait `Extend<&mut u32>` is not implemented for `Vec<u32>`
   |
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Extend<A>`:
             <Vec<T, A> as Extend<T>>
             <Vec<T, A> as Extend<&'a T>>
```

What is the problem and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&mut Vec<u32>`'s iterator yields `&mut u32`. `Vec` cannot be extended from that (it can be extended from iterator over `&u32`, though).

The easiest fix is to use [`extend_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.extend_from_slice):

```rust
fn plus_one(digits: &mut Vec<u32>) -> &Vec<u32> {
    for i in (0..digits.len()).rev() {
        if digits[i] < 10 {
            digits[i] = digits[i] + 1;
            break;
        } else {
            digits[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    if digits[0] == 0 {
        let mut new_digits: Vec<u32> = vec![1];
        new_digits.extend_from_slice(digits);
    }

    digits
}
```

Comment: Alternatively `u32` is `copy` so you could `copied()` the iterator and it'd work fine. Though you'd have to explicitely `iter()` it first obviously, so `extend_from_slice` is likely a better option.

Comment: @Masklinn It also may be less efficient, if LLVM will not optimize this into a memcpy.